# Groovy createCriteria issue with joined table

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy, hibernate-criteria

I have a domain class `Coach` which has a has many relationship to another domain class `CoachProperty`.

Hibernate/Grails is creating a third joined table in the database.

In the example below I am trying to fetch the coaches which both have foo AND bar for their text value. I have tried different solutions with 'or' and 'and' in Grails which either returns an empty list or a list with BOTH foo and bar.

Coach:

```
class Coach {

static hasMany = [ coachProperties : CoachProperty ]
```

CoachProperty:

```
class CoachProperty {

String text
boolean active = true

static constraints = {
    
    text(unique: true, nullable: false, blank: false)
}
}
```

Joined table which is being auto-created and I populated with some data, in this example I am trying to fetch coach 372 since that coach has both 1 and 2 i.e foo and bar:

```
+---------------------------+-------------------+
| coach_coach_properties_id | coach_property_id |
+---------------------------+-------------------+
|                       150 |                 2 |
|                       372 |                 1 |
|                       372 |                 2 |
|                        40 |                 3 |
+---------------------------+-------------------+
```

Inside `Coach.createCriteria().list()` among with other filters. This should return coach 372 but return empty:

```
def tempList = ["foo", "bar"]           
                    coachProperties{
                        for(String temp: tempList){
                            and {
                                log.info "temp = " + temp
                                ilike("text",temp)
                            }
                        }                       
                    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you eliminate the `and {}` block and add an `or {}` block not in the same place as the `and` but instead outside surrounding the `coachProperties` block?

Comment: Still returns empty list, any other ideas?  @JeffScottBrown

Comment: Is it intentional that there are no wildcards in the `temp` variable that you are passing as an argument to the `ilike` method?

Comment: What do you mean by wildcard? this is an hardcoded example of my problem. The real data is a list of ids fetched from frontend dependent on some checkboxes

Comment: Funny thing is that the simple hardcoded version above still gives me the wrong return aasd  @JeffScottBrown

Comment: `"What do you mean by wildcard"` - A percent sign (`%`) is used as a wildcard in `like` and `ilike` expressions.  For example, `%foo%` would match `this has foo in it`, but `foo` would not match `this has foo in it`.

Comment: Alright, i forgot i changed the 'ilike' to 'eq'. I changed back to 'ilike' and added wildcard. The same problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a workaround with executeQuery where ids is the list containing the id's of the coachproperties i was trying to fetch.

```
    def coaches = Coach.executeQuery '''
                    select coach from Coach as coach 
                    join coach.coachProperties as props 
                    where props.id in :ids 
                    group by coach
                    having count(coach) = :count''', [ids: ids.collect { it.toLong() 
                    }, count: ids.size().toLong()]
                        
                    
                    or{
                        coaches.each{ 
                            eq("id", it.id)
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember this error. Was something about not being able to use both nullable & blank at the same time.Try with just 'nullable:true'

Comment: I've tried with only nullable, only blank and removing both. Still gives me empty list. Is it possible for you to check your solution? Still stuck on this problem @Orubel

Comment: My apologies. This was a different error. You don't seem to have a 'belongsTo' in CoachProperty

Comment: You might be right, i fail to see why that would matter though. Would that alter the sql query that is being created behind the scenes?

Comment: You are not making an SQL query. You are making an HQL query. And that requires the domains to properly be joined.

Comment: By adding belongsTo relation would mean that every coachProperty only belongs to one coach which is wrong. Every coachProperty can belong to * coach.

Comment: Well then you have a many to many because you have 'static hasMany = [ coachProperties : CoachProperty ]' in Coach. My suggestion is to create a JOINER TABLE with a primary key and add the other tables as foreign keys.